# CKEDitor removes class names, even with the exception in config

Tags: wysiwyg

CKEditor seems to be stripping out class names when I toggle between HTML view and Rich Text view.

As per many suggestions across the web I have added the following to the config.js file:

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

Uploaded, cleared cache and even gone to the JS file directly to check it is not caching on my machine, but it's still removing classes.

Is there another solution?

Answer (score 18):

Go to "Admin >> Configuration >> CKEditor"; under *Profiles*, choose your profile (e.g. *Full*).

Edit that profile, and on "Advanced Options >> Custom JavaScript configuration" add `config.allowedContent = true;`.

[image: snapshot]

Don't forget to flush the cache under "Performance tab."

Comment: Works for me on Drupal 7 with CKEditor module 7.x-1.13 and CKEditor 4.3.2. Thanks, I was just starting having headache with that !

Comment: Now under "Admin >> Content authoring >> Configuration >> CKEditor".

Answer (score 6):

Edit the full profile in Configuration > CKEditor

[image]

Open the Advanced Content Filter section and select Disabled
[image]

No need to add anything in the Extra Allowed Content field. No need to change the config.js. [...like this hasn't taken me hours and hours to figure out]

Comment: Now under "Admin >> Content authoring >> Configuration >> CKEditor".

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been solved in dev (7.x-2.3 when published) as part of [CKeditor 4.1 ACF](https://drupal.org/node/1956778).
You may try either to upgrade your WYSIWYG or try the below workarounds.

---

In Drupal 7 you can try the following hook:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter(&$settings, $context) {
  if ($context['profile']->editor == 'ckeditor') {
    $settings['allowedContent'] = TRUE;
  }
}
?>
```

or by using some other idea:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter(&$settings, $context) {
  if ($context['profile']->editor == 'ckeditor') {
      $settings['extraAllowedContent'] = array(
        'img[src,title,alt,style,width,height,class,hspace,vspace,view_mode,format,fid]',
      );
  }
}
?>
```

or with the following jQuery code:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( textarea_id, {
    allowedContent: true
} );
```

Related:

- [CKeditor 4 converts Media tags to string "false"](https://drupal.org/node/1963270)
- [CKeditor keeps removing my code when switching in and out of source mode](https://drupal.org/node/1606596)

Answer (score 0):

Go commando and disable the wysiwyg altogether.

If you know how to write basic HTML and CSS, i.e. you're not the client, then turn off the plugin. It'll also improve your HTML/CSS skills

I spent days figuring out how to prevent the wysiwyg butchering my classes and pre/code tags everytime I reloaded the editor. I realised that all I was doing was trying to disable all the wysiwyg plugin functionality. So I turned it off.

Yep, this is contrary to my answer above.