# Classes get stripped out: why?

Tags: wysiwyg, files

I am pasting the following code into the text editor.

```
<ul class="faqs">    
<li class="navbookmark"><a href="#er1">ABC</a></li>
</ul>
```

After the initial save everything looks fine in preview mode. However, if I go back in to edit the page, the styles applied to ul and li tags get stripped out, and the source looks like this.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#er1">ABC</a></li> 
</ul>
```

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: See this thread: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/74778/ckeditor-removes-class-names-even-with-the-exception-in-config

The suggestion there worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't met this problem before. I did Google search and found this link [Classes being stripped in CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/Classes-being-stripped). Maybe your problems come from CKeditor and you just configure the allowedContent for CKeditor.