# Problem adding html to blocks

Tags: blocks, wysiwyg, theming

I seem to have a problem when adding html to a block (i'm using ckk editor), if i toggle Source it loses them html id tag. If I save the Block without toggling, it works fine, but when I go back in to edit the block afterwards, it has lost the div id tag. I have attached a pic which shows the problem in 3 steps. I have it set to Full HTML throughout. [image]

Comment: Just use switch to plain text editor link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thinks, you must twig ckeditor config file, and set config.allowedContent = true. Please, see docs http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules

This links below can help you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659390/ckeditor-automatically-strips-classes-from-div

[CKEDitor removes class names, even with the exception in config](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/74778/ckeditor-removes-class-names-even-with-the-exception-in-config)

Comment: thats fantastic, looking at the link you provided, i was initially tempted to dive in and add the line to config.js, but further down in the chain, i found you can amend the settings under "Admin >> Configuration >> CKEditor", this is explained really well in the link. many thanks.