# How to stop CKEditor from removing alt and title attributes collected by Media Browser

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, media

I am using Media Browser to upload images and when I do there are two fields that collect title and alt attributes. When I save I notice that the attributes are not there and I have to go into CKEditors image properties to re add them.

EDIT:

On CKEditor I click the image icon from the tool bar and i get the Image Properties popup.

When i click the Upload/Browse Server another popup appears with Media Browser.

I Upload an image and see another form asking for filename, alt text, title text and url redirect.

When i fill this info out and press save i am returned to image properties pop up with the image URL filled out but the alternative text field is empty and on the advanced tab the advisory title field is empty.

Comment: Have you tried `config.allowedContent = true;`? It might be removing it.... More info here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/74778#answer-80296

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, no dice though. I'll edit my question to include steps.